# ESlint: validate files by glob pattern

Tags: javascript, eslint

Can I split the ESLint rules by glob pattern?

I mean case like this:

```
{ 
  "*.server.js": { /* rules set for the server JS */ },
  "*.client.js": { /* rules set for the client JS */ },
  "*.special.js": { /* some very special JS */ },
  "*.js": { /* all other JS with its own rules not intersecting with others */ }
}
```

There is the jshint-groups wrapper for JSHint. Is there something like this for ESLint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now possible using an overrides section:

```
{
  "rules": {...},
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": ["*-test.js","*.spec.js"],
      "rules": {
        "no-unused-expressions": "off"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/rules#using-configuration-files-1

Answer (score 2):

Not yet. It's one of the items on the road map for version 2.0.0. For now if you are using grunt/gulp, you can just create multiple tasks with multiple .eslintrc files.